# mail not sending to anyone

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am trying to send out multiple mails, but it seems like it's not working...

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Profil SET Aktiveret = '0' WHERE id='$tjekprofil[id]'");
$modtager = "$tjekprofil[Email]";
$to = '$modtager';
$subject = "VIP hos $Sidenavnf er udløbet!";
$message = "Dit vip medlemsskab er lige udløbet! forny det igen idag!";
$headers = "From: $robotemail";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "sendt mail til $modtager</br>";
```

This is my code, the `echo` spits out both e-mails to send to, it gets the e-mails by `$modtager`, but somehow, `$to` won't take the e-mails from `$modtager`.

Comment: There's about a million similar questions on this subject. Did you see the tiny white box on the top right-hand corner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use single quotes for variable insertions.

Change:

```
$to = '$modtager';
```

to:

```
$to = "$modtager";
```

or even better:

```
$to = $modtager;
```

Comment: oh, okay. that kinda explains everything. I thought it had to be there. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Your welcome and please set the answer as accepted :)

Comment: When I learned PHP a few years back, I was told not to rely on magic replacement of vars in strings. The main argument then was performance (double quotes were supposedly slower because they had to scan for variables), but just for code readability, you should avoid that entirely and solely use explicit concatenation in order to avoid this king of issues (`$name = 'John'; $greeting = 'Hello ' . $name . '!';`).